# Database INSERT not saving

Tags: .net, sql-server

I have created a function called addPeople() with the parameters of firstname and lastname.
When the user inputs the first and last name and clicks the add button, the new entry is added to the database. However, once the program is restarted, the newly added entry is gone and wasn't saved. Why is this? How can I actually save the new data?

```
Sub addPeople(ByVal fname As String, ByVal lname As String)
        Dim conn As SqlConnection
        conn = New SqlConnection(getConnectionString)

        Dim cmd As New SqlCommand
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text
        
        cmd.Connection = conn

        ' Open the connection '
        conn.Open()
        ' Start the "transaction" so the insert saves to the database '
        cmd.CommandText = "BEGIN TRANSACTION"
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
        ' Insert the new data into the database '
        cmd.CommandText = "INSERT people (firstname, lastname) VALUES ('" + fname + "', '" + lname + "')"
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
        ' Save the changes to the database '
        cmd.CommandText = "COMMIT"
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
        ' Close the connection '
        conn.Close()
    End Sub
```

I've tried starting the transaction and then using COMMIT to make sure the changes are saved, but that still doesn't work.

Edit:
After some further testing, I've also noticed my deletePeople() function also doesn't fully save the changes to the database.

```
Sub deletePeople(ByVal id As String)
        Dim conn As SqlConnection
        conn = New SqlConnection(getConnectionString)

        Dim cmd As New SqlCommand
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text

        cmd.Connection = conn

        ' Open the connection '
        conn.Open()
        ' Start the "transaction" so the insert saves to the database '
        cmd.CommandText = "BEGIN TRANSACTION"
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
        ' Insert the new data into the database '
        cmd.CommandText = "DELETE FROM people WHERE people_id='" + id + "'"
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
        ' Save the changes to the database '
        cmd.CommandText = "COMMIT"
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
        ' Close the connection '
        conn.Close()
    End Sub
```

```
ConnectionString = "Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\Database1.mdf;Integrated Security=True"
```

Comment: How do you know it worked and the result was not "0 rows inserted"?  Also, using raw input in a SQL query is very dangerous, see the story of Little Bobby Tables: https://xkcd.com/327

Comment: @DaveS Upon clicking the add button, a DataGridView control gets updated/refreshed with the newly added data

Comment: Why do you use BEGIN TRANSACTION without also doing an END TRANSACTION?

Comment: @KenWhite Well, the first reason is the example I originally looked at didn't have an END TRANSACTION but instead stated the COMMIT ends the transaction. The second reason is that I originally tried using END TRANSACTION after doing the COMMIT, however, I would just get an error stating theres an incorrect syntax near TRANSACTION in my END TRANSACTION

Comment: You don't specify what version of sql. I'm guessing since you are using .net that it's the file based SQL, and for this particular development environment setup it gets recreated everytime you run the project. Can you please post your connection string as that will help verify

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid I have edited the post to include the connection string

Comment: Then [edit] your post to add a tag for the specific RDBMS you're using.

Comment: [SQL Injection alert](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms161953%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) - you should **not** concatenate together your SQL statements - use **parametrized queries** instead to avoid SQL injection - check out [Little Bobby Tables](http://bobby-tables.com/)

Answer (score 1):

Instead of this:

```
cmd.CommandText = "BEGIN TRANSACTION"
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
```

You want to Begin the Transaction on the Connection:

```
var transaction = connection.BeginTransaction()
```

All up:

```
using (var transaction = connection.BeginTransaction())
{
    cmd.CommandText = "INSERT people (firstname, lastname) VALUES ('" + fname + "', '" + lname + "')";
    cmd.Transaction = transaction;
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    transaction.Commit();
    //transaction.Rollback();
}
```